# Pandas shift based on different values to calculate percentages

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to calculate percentages of first down from a dataframe.

Here is the dataframe

```
        down  distance
1        1.0      10.0
2        2.0      13.0
3        3.0      15.0
4        3.0      20.0
5        4.0       1.0
6        1.0      10.0
7        2.0       9.0
8        3.0       3.0
9        1.0      10.0
```

I would like to calculate the percent from first down, meaning for second down, what is the percent of yards gained. For third down, perc of third based on first.

For example, I would like to have the following output.

```
        down  distance    percentage

1        1.0      10.0    NaN
2        2.0      13.0    (13-10)/13
3        3.0      15.0    (15-10)/15
4        3.0      20.0    (20-10)/20
5        4.0       1.0    (1-10)/20
6        1.0      10.0    NaN       # New calculation
7        2.0       9.0    (9-10)/9
8        3.0       3.0    (3-10)/3
9        1.0      10.0    NaN
```

Thanks

Current solutions all work correctly for the first question.

Comment: I think there's a typo.. shouldn't it be `(1-10)/1` in row 5?

Comment: It does look like a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a vectorised solution:

```
# define condition
cond = df['down'] == 1

# calculate value to subtract
first = df['distance'].where(cond).ffill().mask(cond)

# perform calculation
df['percentage'] = (df['distance'] - first) / df['distance']

print(df)

   down  distance  percentage
1   1.0      10.0         NaN
2   2.0      13.0    0.230769
3   3.0      15.0    0.333333
4   3.0      20.0    0.500000
5   4.0       1.0   -9.000000
6   1.0      10.0         NaN
7   2.0       9.0   -0.111111
8   3.0       3.0   -2.333333
9   1.0      10.0         NaN
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing!  Both algorithmically and that it is beautiful.

Answer (score 2):

Using `groupby` and `transform`:

```
s = df.groupby(df.down.eq(1).cumsum()).distance.transform('first')
s = df.distance.sub(s).div(df.distance)
df['percentage'] = s.mask(s.eq(0))

   down  distance  percentage
1   1.0      10.0         NaN
2   2.0      13.0    0.230769
3   3.0      15.0    0.333333
4   3.0      20.0    0.500000
5   4.0       1.0   -9.000000
6   1.0      10.0         NaN
7   2.0       9.0   -0.111111
8   3.0       3.0   -2.333333
9   1.0      10.0         NaN
```

Comment: Thanks! Already +1 for you :) I think `ffill` is going to be faster than `transform('first')`

Comment: This is a solid answer!

Answer (score 2):

## With Numpy Bits

Should be pretty zippy!

```
m = df.down.values == 1                # mask where equal to 1
i = np.flatnonzero(m)                  # positions where equal to 1
d = df.distance.values                 # Numpy array of distances

j = np.diff(np.append(i, len(df)))     # use diff to find distances between
                                       # values equal to 1.  Note that I append
                                       # the length of the df as a terminal value

k = i.repeat(j)                        # I repeat the positions where equal to 1
                                       # a number of times in order to fill in.
p = np.where(m, np.nan, 1 - d[k] / d)  # reduction of % formula while masking

df.assign(percentage=p)

   down  distance  percentage
1   1.0      10.0         NaN
2   2.0      13.0    0.230769
3   3.0      15.0    0.333333
4   3.0      20.0    0.500000
5   4.0       1.0   -9.000000
6   1.0      10.0         NaN
7   2.0       9.0   -0.111111
8   3.0       3.0   -2.333333
9   1.0      10.0         NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

use groupby to group by each time `down` is equal to 1, than transform with your desired calculation. Then you can find where `down` is 1 again, and convert to `NaN` (as the calculation is meaningless there, as per your example):

```
df['percentage'] = (df.groupby(df.down.eq(1).cumsum())['distance']
                .transform(lambda x: (x-x.iloc[0])/x))


df.loc[df.down.eq(1),'percentage'] = np.nan

>>> df
   down  distance  percentage
1   1.0      10.0         NaN
2   2.0      13.0    0.230769
3   3.0      15.0    0.333333
4   3.0      20.0    0.500000
5   4.0       1.0   -9.000000
6   1.0      10.0         NaN
7   2.0       9.0   -0.111111
8   3.0       3.0   -2.333333
9   1.0      10.0         NaN
```